# What is the advantage of having a small stack of a thread?

Tags: c, operating-system, pthreads, posix, embedded-linux

I am studying POSIX threads and saw that there is a way to change the stack size; I am still a layman in general operating systems; so what is the benefit of having a small stack, will i have memory savings at runtime? type in embedded systems?

Comment: One factor: Each thread requires a seperate stack. So a smaller stack will allow for more concurrent threads. Though one would need to seriously reconsider the design of any app which has so many threads that this becomes an issue.

Comment: sure, each thread gets a stack, that stack is 8Mb by default in the linuxes I've seen. If you make that smaller then you'll save some memory. Unless you're working with an embedded device with very limited resources, I wouldn't worry about it. Memory is cheap and abundant these days, I've never modified the stack size.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I thought the same thing as you, but always good to try to see a different point from yours, hehe

Comment: On an OS that doesn't allocate until a page is touched (like Linux), it most likely costs nothing to have a larger stack.

Comment: Note that giving your threads a *smaller* stack is not the only way to make use of the ability to set stack size -- you can also make it *larger*.  This could be important if your threads use many large, stack-allocated objects, for example.

Comment: @stark: That's not true, and misses that "allocates" is underdefined. No matter what, the virtual address space must be allocated immediately, and on any modern 32-bit system this is going to be the limiting factor. In addition, if commit accounting is enabled (so that you don't run into surprise OOM-killing), it will be allocated in the sense of commit too. The only case in which it's not "allocated", then, is just that the memory can be used as cache until it's (possibly never) needed as stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what is the benefit of having a small stack

The major benefit is that you can create more threads.

On 32-bit OSes (4GiB address space), using 8MiB stack allows you to create a maximum of 512 threads. In reality, you will run out of virtual address much faster, as the kernel usually reserves 1/2 to 1/4 of total address space, and heap and shared libraries fragment the available address space more.

If you are running server processes (think web search), you may want to use "one thread per connection" model, which then limits how many simultaneous connections you can handle on a single machine. Even 10 years ago, 500 threads was way too few compared to what the processor was capable of.

Address space exhaustion is less of a concern with 64-bit OSes.

In addition, once a thread used significant amount of stack, that memory is "stranded".

Imagine you have a web server which handles 1000s of requests per second. If most requests use (say) 32KiB of stack, but an occasional rare request uses 2MiB of stack, and if the requests are distributed randomly across a pool of threads, eventually every thread will have used 2MiB of RAM, and so your process will continue to use N*2MiB of RAM despite only needing N*32KiB 99.99% of the time.

You can avoid such stranding of RAM if you force your threads to use no more than (say) 64KiB of stack.

Having this extra RAM allows you to run other tasks on the same machine (which is how many cloud service providers are able to sell their "excess capacity" at very low cost).

Comment: Hehe, now I can better understand when I can decrease a thread's stack